# RedpinAndroid: Running the client app

Tags: android, positioning

I am trying to run the indoor positioning app called RedpinAndroid on Nexus5. I am able to create an apk after a lot of work and surfing. The app launches successfully now but it doesnot show anything on screen. Not even a map.

There is a location button on left bottom that displays a progress bar on clicking it but after some time it shows "no matching location found". Do I need to configure application with some predefined locations? I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Is this any programming related question or how to use an app? , Could please convey what you have written and what is the problem you have faced?

Comment: RedpinAndroid is an indoor positioning app that helps you to locate particular locations with accuracy. It is a specific open source app. Someone who has used it can only answer my question. Thanks

Comment: Have you followed all the steps mentioned here http://redpin.org/android.html